# Plot rolling coefficients and color based on P-Value

Tags: r, plot, rolling-computation

This is somewhat tricky! I am running a rolling window of a regression and I am collecting all the coefficients for each window. My goal is to plot how the coefficient fluctuates over time. Furthermore, I would like the plot to give a different color for when the coefficient was found statistically significant (say at the 95%) by being giving a different color point when not significant.

What I have so far is:

```
library(plm)
coeff<-NULL
for(e in 1:39){   #44 years total for each country
      paneldata<-pdata.frame(
rbind(
subset(LaggedPannel,Country=="A")[(e):(e+5),],
subset(LaggedPannel,Country=="B")[(e):(e+5),]),
index=c("Country","Year")) #we made our new windowed panel frame


coef<-coef(summary(plm(Y~lag(Y,1),data=paneldata,model="pooling")))[2,1] #gets the coeff from a panel regression
      coeff<-c(coeff,coef)  #store coeffs
    } 
plot(coeff,type="b",col="red")
```

The plot yielded: [image: the figure]

For example say the 2nd and 4th coefficients (bullets in the plot) are statistically insignificant; then their color should have been green.

`Data (LaggedPannel)`:

```
                 Age1     Age2     Age3
Australia-1973  261.156  255.699  249.954
Australia-1974  261.305  255.394  251.470
Australia-1975  258.160  253.543  250.538
Australia-1976  262.504  258.066  254.720
Australia-1977  240.086  260.846  258.418
Australia-1978  228.774  238.871  259.449
USA-1973       4100.257 4104.028 4107.409
USA-1974       4135.435 4118.422 4120.286
USA-1975       4171.648 4164.065 4134.525
USA-1976       4208.236 4187.196 4171.167
USA-1977       4240.832 4211.655 4189.650
USA-1978       4286.923 4255.092 4229.701
```

Comment: Can you paste the result of `dput(df)` whatever your dataframe `df` might be?

Comment: added a small sample of the dataset to see. They are in a panel data format. The original dataset is quite huge to put the whole `dput(df)` result. Hopefully this is helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an extra vector for storing the p-values and then coloring based on their value compared to the 0.05 significance level solves as well the issue. Specifically:

```
library(plm)
coeff<-NULL
P_values<-NULL
for(e in 1:39){   #44 years total for each country
      paneldata<-pdata.frame(
rbind(
subset(LaggedPannel,Country=="A")[(e):(e+5),],
subset(LaggedPannel,Country=="B")[(e):(e+5),]),
index=c("Country","Year")) #we made our new windowed panel frame


coef<-coef(summary(plm(Y~lag(Y,1),data=paneldata,model="pooling")))[2,1] #gets the coeff from a panel regression
PV<-coef(summary(plm(Y~lag(Y,1),data=paneldata,model="pooling")))[2,4] #stores the p-values
coeff<-c(coeff,coef)
P_values<-c(P_values,PV)
    } 
plot(coeff,type="b",col="red") #previousplot
```

[image: Before]

```
 plot(coeff,col=ifelse(P_values<=0.05, "blue", "red"),ylab = "coef",type="b") 
    #new plot based on significant values:
```

[image: After]

The only issue with this answer is that it quite tedious if you have more than a few variables to consider; then you would need to create more than a few empty vectors and so on. It isn't a fast approach, but for sure it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some simulated data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
simfun <- function(a=0.1,B=0.05,n=200,x.sd=1,e.sd=1) {
  x <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=x.sd) + runif(100)
  e <-  rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=e.sd)
  y <- a+B*x+e 
  data.frame(x,y)
}

statfun <- function(d) {
  summary(lm(y~x,data=d)) %>% tidy()
}

simdata <- map(seq(50),~statfun(simfun())) %>% enframe() %>% unnest() %>% filter(term == "x")
```

Below determines which coefficients are "significant".

```
simdata <- simdata %>% 
  mutate(row_number(),
         Significance = factor(p.value < 0.05))
```

If you want to use base `plot`, you can do:

```
Significance = simdata$Significance

plot(simdata$estimate, col = ifelse(Significance==TRUE, "blue", "red"), ylab = "coeff")
lines(simdata$estimate)
```

[image]

Or with `ggplot2`, you can do:

```
ggplot(simdata, aes(name, estimate)) + geom_line() + geom_point(aes(color = Significance), shape = 1) +
  labs(x = "Index", y = "coeff") + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting but I find that your answer is not coherent with the panel approach. I am completely unfamiliar with the `tidyverse` functions, thus i cannot connect your answer to my problem. What i mean is that each loop updates the dataset and creates basically a new one which then is used in a panel regression. I do not see that happening in the `map` function (maybe I am missing something).

Comment: but your answer gave a small idea on how to fix it!